# Install package with composer, set a new package namespace

Tags: php, composer-php

how can I install a new package with Composer, and use it with my specified namespace?

By default, package comes with "Respect\Stringifier\stringify", but this namespace is not suitable for me.

I need to change it to "Acme\Respect\Stringifier\stringify".

```
My project structure:
/httdocs
    /test
        /index.php
        /src
            /vendors
            /composer.json
                /autoload.php
                /respect
                    /stringifier
```

Here is my index.php file

```
<?php

use function Acme\Respect\Stringifier\stringify;

include('src/vendor/autoload.php');

echo stringify(['a']);
```

composer.json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "respect/stringifier": "^0.2.0"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\": "vendor/"
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should that be possible? The package uses a namespace specified by the package. Modifying that namespace might have tons of consequences, like problems with dynamically generated class names or service definitions in a DI container

Comment: Which problem are you trying to resolve by changing the namespace? Also, the folder structure looks strange, as Composer would never put any packages in a folder named `composer.json`, side by side to an `autoload.php`

Comment: "By default, package comes with "Respect\Stringifier\stringify", but this namespace is not suitable for me." Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests a bit of confusion over how namespaces and Composer work. The general idea is to separate out two types of code:

- Third-party packages, which Composer will manage for you, and should be treated as read-only. They will have whatever namespace and class names their authors choose.
- Your *own* code, which lives *beside* this, with whatever directory and namespace structure you choose.

So your `composer.json` might look like this:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "respect/stringifier": "^0.2.0"
    },
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\": "src/"
        }        
    }
}
```

Which says to install third-party code in the default location (`vendor/`), and load your own classes in namespaces beginning `Acme\` from the directory `src/`. Both directories are next to the `composer.json` file, not nested inside each other.

Your code layout would then look like this:

```
composer.json
index.php
src/
    Products/
         Shoe.php
vendor/
    autoload.php (created by Composer)
    respect/
         stringifier/
               (third-party code)
```

Then in `index.php` you could write this:

```php
<?php

use function Respect\Stringifier\stringify;
use Acme\Products\Shoe;

// Note: use __DIR__ to make an absolute path
// and don't use parentheses, as they are not needed and can be misleading
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

echo stringify(['a']);
// short for echo \Respect\Stringifier\stringify(['a']);
// loaded from vendor/respect/stringifier according to the package's config

$shoe = new Shoe;
// short for $shoe = new \Acme\Products\Shoe;
// loaded from src/Products/Shoe.php according to your psr-4 config in composer.json
```